# Question marks in cross-referencing after using pdflatex command

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing, compiling, windows

I am working on a software, to automatically generate `*.tex`-files with some predefined and generated text inside.

After generating the files, I am calling the Windows command line (CMD) and try to create a `*.pdf`-file from the `*.tex`-file using the `pdflatex` command. For example:

```
pdflatex myfile.tex
```

It works fine but unfortunately instead of the cross-references I only see question marks in my PDF. If I open the `*.tex`-file in TeXStudio and convert from there, the cross-references are created correctly.

Why does `pdflatex` have problems creating the cross-references correctly?

Comment: Did you run `pdflatex` twice?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, consider Joseph Wright comment. To appear cross references in text you need to compile your file at least twice. In the first run references is written in `.aux` file and in the second to the your text file (roughly said).

Comment: Thank you very much guys! This worked perfectly. Didn't know I have to run it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments under my question, I found out, that the `pdflatex`-command has to be run **twice**.

Quote (Zarko):

> To appear
>   cross references in text you need to compile your file at least twice.
>   In the first run references is written in .aux file and in the second
>   to the your text file (roughly said).